# Android: floating point virtual keyboard on Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

In my app on the `EditText` I need to show virtual keyboard for floating point value. 
I have  `NumberEditText` class that is inherited from `EditText`. In it's constructor I do this

```
// set digital keyboard
setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)
// add allowed input 
keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,")
```

This works perfectly, I see the keyboard with digits and `.`

[image]

But when I open the app on Samsung Galaxy S5 there is no `.` on the keyboard, I can enter only integer values but not floating point ones.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: How about using **`android:digits="1234567890.,"
        android:inputType="number"`** this

Comment: doesnt worked above solution